# Installing wine for the first time in the terminal stays stuck on [working]

Tags: linux-mint, wine

I'm trying to install wine doesn't give me any errors, but putting either linux mint 1.7x or linux mint 1.8x in the first couple seconds updating the packages it stays stuck on `[working]` and doesn't do anything is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Again i'm sorry that its hard to explain, i'm just trying to install wine, but on the website https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu <-- this is the version i'm trying to install and even though I put ALL of the commands in the terminal (I tried both of the linux mint versions that it shows and it just stays stuck on `[working]`) after putting `sudo apt-get update` Again sorry that this is a bad post, i'm not much of a tech person like this.

Comment: Please, tell me the Linux flavour you are using. Is it Linux mint, or Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure I changed the operating system to a linux but this is a acer chromebook. How does one check? But I think its Ubuntu or GalliumOS (At least it says GalliumOS on my home screen)

Answer (score 0):

You had added too many lines of trusty repo in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

First get the lines that include trusty repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -n trusty
```

Then remove the lines :

```
sudo sed -i.bak -e '13d;14d;15d;20d;22d;26d;27d;' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then update and install packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```